# How to realize long-range interaction of colds atom in an optical lattice?

Tags: experimental-physics, experimental-technique, cold-atoms

In the Bose-Hubbard model of cold atoms in an optical lattice, we consider only the short-range interaction or on-site interaction. Is it possible to realize long-range interaction similar to Coulomb interaction in the cold atom experiment?

Answer (score 2):

A way to get long-range interactions in cold atoms is to use polar molecules, which is a rapidly growing field in the cold atoms community.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the introduction of e.g. [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1103.2096) for an example of long range Van der Waals forces, which are encountered in cold atom experiments. These forces occur between highly excited atoms called Rydberg atoms and behave as $n^{11}/r^6$, where $n$ is the principal quantum number, which is extraordinary high for these atoms.